# Replace wrong lines in csv

Tags: regex, linux, replace, sed, grep

I have a csv file like that :

```
0;test1;description;toto
1;test2;description;tata
2;test3;desc
ription;tutu
3;test4;description;tete
```

In shell, I would like to replace all the line that doesn't start with a number. 
In this exemple I want to replace \nription by ription

I don't find the correct expression with sed, grep... :(

I want this result :

```
0;test1;description;toto
1;test2;description;tata
2;test3;description;tutu
3;test4;description;tete
```

Thanks a lot

EDIT 1 :
I have try something like this :

```
LC_ALL=C tr '(\n)[0-9]' ' ' < hotels.csv > test.csv
```

Or this :

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n?![0-ç-9]/ /g' hotels.csv
```

But i think my regex is wrong and it doesn't work :(

Comment: How about vim? `:v/^\d/-1j` would do it.

Comment: I can't use vim because it's going to be in a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` this seems feasible:

```
awk -F ';' '{if (NR>1  && match($1,/^[0-9]+$/)) printf("\n"); printf("%s",$0);} END{printf("\n")}' infile.csv
```

What it does:

- from the second line: check if first field is a number and print a newline
- in any line: print the entire line (`$0`) without trailing newline

Output is sent to `STDOUT`, input comes from `infile.csv`

EDIT: Sorry, i missed to copy the match(...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the result is the same.
I have try something like this :

    LC_ALL=C tr '(\n)[0-9]' ' ' < hotels.csv > test.csv

Or this :

    sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n?![0-ç-9]/ /g' hotels.csv 

But i think my regex is wrong :(

Comment: Thanks but in my file it doesn't work. It replaces all new lines.

I don't understand because if I use a new csv file it works :(

Comment: Do you have made an export from a spreadsheet as Excel? The line break may not be a newline ```\n```. So try to find the line breaking character with ```hexdump -C``` and then eliminate it with ```sed  's/\x0D/' infule.csv```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -P`

```
grep -P "^\d" file.csv
```

Use grep to match lines that begin with a digit.

Answer (score 0):

due to peculiarities of `sed`'s pattern space processing, you will have to use something like this ..

Note: `~` must be a char not present in your text

```
$cat file
0;test1;description;toto
1;test2;description;tata
2;test3;desc
ription;tutu
3;test4;description;tete
$ sed 'N;s/\n/~/' file | sed -r 's/~([0-9])/\n\1/g;s/~//g'
0;test1;description;toto
1;test2;description;tata
2;test3;description;tutu
3;test4;description;tete
```

PS: if your input file has Windows line endings you will have to use `\r\n` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/3;desc/,"3;description;tutu")}NR == 4 {next}1' file
0;test1;description;toto
1;test2;description;tata
2;test3;description;tutu
3;test4;description;tete
```